# Stm32 ADC (via DMA) Error code 4 when restaring the ADC(DMA)

Tags: c, arduino, arm, stm32, stm32f0

The Code is generated by CubeIde(Mx).

So on the second run of the main loop the ADC Error register reads 4 and stops working (Status register reads 320).
The ADC is configured to read 2 Channels (1.5 cycles) (scan forward) and the ADC clock is the main clock divided by 4 (48/4=12MHz).
The DMA is configured as half word and circular.
The timers are configured to 40kHz.

I have checked that the used array are correct size. The optimization does not seam to change the behavior.

```
HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc); //ADC SETUP
HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc);
HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim1);

/* USER CODE END 2 */

/* Infinite loop */
/* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
while (1) {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    cc = 0;
    flag = 1; //Start

    HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim3);
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_4);

    while (flag != 0) {    // Measurement on going
        //HAL_Delay(1);
        if (flag == 0) {
            HAL_ADC_Stop_DMA(&hadc);
        }
    }

    HAL_ADC_Stop_DMA(&hadc);
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 800; ++i) {

        sprintf(asic_buffer, "%d", guffer[i]);
        asic_buffer[4] = 0;
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, asic_buffer, 5, 20);
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, new_line, 2, 8);

    }

    HAL_Delay(1);
}
```

the fist interrupt

```
void TIM3_IRQHandler(void) {
/* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_IRQn 0 */
if (flag == 1) {

    flag_c++;
    if (flag_c >= pulse) {
        flag = 2;  //Listening
        flag_c = 0;

        HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT(&htim3);
        HAL_TIM_Base_Stop(&htim1);

        HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc, (uint32_t*) buffera, 8); //ADC Start

        //pos = 0;
        //datacounter = 0;
    }

}
 /* USER CODE END TIM3_IRQn 0 */
 HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim3);
 /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_IRQn 1 */
}
```

the second interrupt

```
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef *hadc) {

if (cc * 4 >= 800) {

    flag = 0;
 }

 ++cc;
}
```

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: `Status register reads 320` decimal values are perfect for debugging. Translate it to the bits with human names

Answer (score 0):

The error lies with in the  HAL_ADC_Stop_DMA(&hadc) witch should be  HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc).
i don't know why but it solves the Error.

Comment: no one knows. it is a beauty of HAL. instead of 10 les of bare register code you have 200 and you do not even know why it works. lovely